# Rewrite URL to append specific parameters as query string using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, seo

So I have a scenario where I want to grab certain parameters(optional) from URL and append them as query string to rewritten URL.

```
https://www.example.org/services/state.php?state=TX&city=Austin&{other 0 or 1 or 2 or 3 optional parameters}
```

To

```
https://www.example.org/services/tx/austin/?{query string(containing all optional parameters after City)}
```

Please note the **/?** at the end of City of desired URL. Also I want the rewritten URL in **lower case**.
I am able to rewrite URL from

```
https://www.example.org/services/state.php?state=TX&city=Austin
```

To

```
https://www.example.org/services/TX/Austin/
```

using following code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^services/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ /services/state.php?state=$1&city=$2 [END]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^state=([A-Za-z]+)&city=([A-Za-z]+)$
RewriteRule ^services/state\.php$ services/%1/%2/ [QSD,R=301,END]
```

but unable to acheive the full desired output. I have tried following code to no avail:

```
RewriteRule ^services/([a-z]{2})/([a-z]+)/(.*)$ /services/state.php?state=$1&city=$2&$3 [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^state=([a-zA-Z]{2})&city=([a-zA-Z]+)&?(.*)$
RewriteRule ^services/state.php$ /services/%1/%2/?%3 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Not sure what the question is supposed to be here, regarding the parameters. The second block you have shown, should redirect from `/services/state.php?state=TX&city=Austin&foo=bar` to `/services/TX/Austin/?foo=bar` - so how exactly is that not working?

Comment: _"Also I want the rewritten URL in lower case."_ - then you would probably need to use a RewriteMap, https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/rewritemap.html#int RewriteMap can only be configured in server config or virtual host though; some of the functions can be used without a RewriteMap with a high enough Apache version though I think (not sure on the details here.)